# Microsoft Word Wildcards Dates

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I have  Word document with dates. Dates are writen in format: d. m. yyyy . (15. 12. 2018, 8. 9. 2018...). I would like replace space in dates with non breaking space. I allready try to find  `(<??>). (<??>). (<????>)`and replace with `\1. \2. \3`

In replaced text I use CTRL+ALT+SPACE. This work OK for dates where are two digit num. but it isn't ok for one digi num. 5. 8. 2019.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could find and replace 4 times.  1 (<??>). (<??>). (<????>)   2  (<??>). (<?>). (<????>)  3  (<?>). (<??>). (<????>)  4  (<?>). (<?>). (<????>)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I was wondering if there is one solution for all.